# How to recreate symbols in latex

Tags: symbols

[[image: [1]]

I need to be able to represent these symbols, how would I do this? thanks

Comment: Hi garry and [welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). In its current form, your question might not receive many answers. Please take a look at the [How to Ask](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)-page and try to improve your question according to the guidance found there. This may require you to show some effort on your part in terms of attempting a solution. If you have questions about what to do or if you don't quite understand what this means, please ask for clarification using the `add comment` function.

Answer (score 2):

The first symbol can be written with \sqsubseteq, 
the second symbol can be written with \equiv,
the third symbol can be written with \neg.

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html is a good link for finding the codes for symbols.

Comment: +1 for detexify... Seriously, that service has helped me a ton of times with symbols. Not only relatively strange ones, but also simple ones I just couldn't remember the command for (\in I'm looking at you).